# Confusion with the use of logical operators in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-injection

I have a table called `users` as below :

[image]

Now when I run a query as :

```
select * from users where name='admin1' AND 1;
```

I get as output only the `admin1` record as shown below:
[image]

While with the query as:

```
select * from users where name='admin1' OR 1;
```

I get as output all the records as shown below:
[image]

I am trying to understand why is this happening. IMHO, if we are talking of evaluating the logical expression, both the queries above evaluate to 1 as they are both

> 1 AND 1

and

> 1 OR 1

So why this difference ? Or is there something fundamental that I am perhaps missing ?

Comment: "<x> AND 1" returns whatever "<x>" is, which might be either true or false.  "<x> OR 1" always returns true, because "1" is always true.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't place password hashes on a public forum.. But because these passsword hashes looks to be blowfish they can't be cracked using rainbow tables that's your luck

Comment: The only difference is for 'AND' it should satisfy both the conditions whereas for 'OR' it can be any one of the condition to be satisfied. 

So, when you are verifying with 'name="admin1" AND 1' it is validating the value as well with 1=1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks. I knew I was being stupid. This is so clear and so basic. Thanks again !

Comment: @RaymondNijland agreed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the @DanoPlurana's answer, that I consider correct.

I would strongly discourage to write queries this way since they do not conform to the SQL standard, and they are difficult to read. If you are confused about their meaning, I bet the next developer(s) who read it after you for maintenance will also be. And this produces **real defects** in production, and **real loss of money** for your clients.

Just write normal boolean conditions and make life easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. First query must satisfy both conditions so the name must be 'admin1' and 1 is always true. That is why you get only one row as a result with name admin1

Only one of the conditions must be satisfied in the second query, that is why you get all results from your table

[image]

Comment: (NOT is a unary operator.  The picture shows `NOT ( A OR B )`.)